# Initialising a class and class method for calculating the density of humid air in Python

Tags: python, class

I've started trying to learn Python this morning and tried to create a class to calculate the density of air at a given a pressure, temperature and relative humidity. A good explanation of the method I'm using can be found [here](https://www.gribble.org/cycling/air_density.html).

My class code is below:

```
class Density:

SpecificGasConstantDryAir = 287.0531
SpecificGasConstantWaterVapour = 461.4964

def __init__(self, Pressure_hPa, Temp_C, RelativeHumidty):
    self.Pressure_hPa = Pressure_hPa
    self.Temp_C = Temp_C
    self.RelativeHumity = RelativeHumidty


def Pressure_Pa(self):
    return self.Pressure_hPa*100

def Temp_K(self):
    return self.Temp_C+273.15

def Es_Pa(self):
    Eso = 6.1078
    c0 = 0.99999683
    c1 = -0.90826951*10**-2
    c2 = 0.78736169*10**-4
    c3 = -0.61117958*10**-6
    c4 = 0.43884187*10**-8
    c5 = -0.29883885*10**-10
    c6 = 0.21874425*10**-12
    c7 = -0.17892321*10**-14
    c8 = 0.11112018*10**-16
    c9 = -0.30994571*10**-19
    p = c0+Temp_C*(c1+Temp_C*(c2+Temp_C*(c3+Temp_C*(c4+Temp_C*(c5+Temp_C*(c6+Temp_C*(c7+Temp_C*(c8+Temp_C*(c9)))))))))
    Es_hPa = Eso/(p**8)
    return Es_hPa*100

def PartialPressureWaterVapour_Pa(self):
    return Es_Pa*RelativeHumidity

def PartialPressureDryAir_Pa(self):
    return Pressure_Pa-PartialPressureWaterVapour_Pa

def DensityHumidAir(self):
    return PartialPressureDryAir_Pa/(SpecificGasConstantDryAir*Temp_K)+PartialPressureWaterVapour_Pa/(SpecificGasConstantWaterVapour*Temp_K)
```

My code to initialise the class and return DensityHumidAir is:

```
AmbientAir = Density(1029, 15, 0.5)
print AmbientAir.DensityHumidAir
```

This returns the error `<bound method Density.DensityHumidAir of <__main__.Density instance at 0x02CCF440>>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call the function with `()`, e.g. `AmbientAir.DensityHumidAir()`

Comment: Good spot but that can't be the only issue... `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EngineCalculations\src\densitycalculation.py", line 44, in <module>
    print AmbientAir.DensityHumidAir()
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EngineCalculations\src\densitycalculation.py", line 41, in DensityHumidAir
    return PartialPressureDryAir_Pa/(SpecificGasConstantDryAir*Temp_K)+PartialPressureWaterVapour_Pa/(SpecificGasConstantWaterVapour*Temp_K)
NameError: global name 'PartialPressureDryAir_Pa' is not defined`

Comment: You must refer to other methods via `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function with `()`, e.g. `AmbientAir.DensityHumidAir()`.

Also, within the class, two issues:

1. When referencing functions or variables within the class, use `self.function_name` or `self.variable_name`, otherwise it can't find them.
2. Make sure you're calling these functions too. None of the functions are being called.

Comment: Good spot but that can't be the only issue... `Traceback (most recent call last):` `File "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EngineCalculations‌​\src\densitycalculat‌​ion.py", line 44, in <module>` `print AmbientAir.DensityHumidAir()` `File "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EngineCalculations‌​\src\densitycalculat‌​ion.py", line 41, in DensityHumidAir` `return PartialPressureDryAir_Pa/(SpecificGasConstantDryAir*Temp_K)+‌​PartialPressureWater‌​Vapour_Pa/(SpecificG‌​asConstantWaterVapou‌​r*Temp_K)` `NameError: global name 'PartialPressureDryAir_Pa' is not defined`

Comment: Many thanks for your patience, they were really silly mistakes but I just couldn't spot them myself.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) I'd appreciate an upvote in addition to the answer accept ;)